# How to read the following text file as json?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, type-conversion

File:

```
random_seed: 42
dataset_config {
  data_sources {
    abc: "xyz"
    def: "qwerty"
  }
}
```

I tried:

```
import json
import ast
with open(raw_data) as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.splitlines()

def Convert(a):
    it = iter(a)
    res_dct = dict(zip(it, it))
    return res_dct

data = Convert(data)

print(data)
```

What I got:
{'random_seed: 42': 'dataset_config {', '  data_sources {': '    abc: "xyz"', '    def: "qwerty"': '  }'}

Comment: `json.load(open(raw_data))` assuming it is json ecoded... which your example is not

Comment: Yes, data does not have valid json

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's because the text file you are using doesn't have a valid JSOn format. you can maybe try something like this:

```
import json

# Parsing the text file and storing it in a dictionary
data = {}
current_key = None
current_dict = None
with open(raw_data) as f:
    for line in f:
        if '{' in line:
            # Start a new dictionary
            current_dict = {}
            data[current_key] = current_dict
        elif '}' in line:
            # End the current dictionary
            current_dict = None
            current_key = None
        else:
            # Split the line into a key and value
            key, value = line.strip().split(': ')
            if current_dict is not None:
                # Add the key-value pair to the current dictionary
                current_dict[key] = value
            else:
                # Save the key for the next dictionary
                current_key = key

# Converting the dictionary to a JSON string
json_data = json.dumps(data)

# Looading the JSON string into a Python object
json_obj = json.loads(json_data)

#Finallly printing it
print(json_obj)
```

### Updated:

Okay, now lets try putting the quotes around the key and the vlues.

```
import json
import re

# opening the text file and read the contents into a string
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

# sarting an empty dictionary to store the parsed data
json_data = {}

# breaking the text into lines
lines = text.split('\n')

# looping through each line
for line in lines:
    # Match lines with key-value pairs
    match = re.match(r'^(\w+):(.+)$', line)
    if match:
        # Extract the key and value from the match
        key = match.group(1)
        value = match.group(2)

        # parsing the value as a JSON object if it is surrounded by curly braces
        if value.startswith('{') and value.endswith('}'):
            # Fixing the value to be in valid JSON format by adding quotes around the keys and values
            fixed_value = re.sub(r'(\w+):', '"\\1":', value)
            value = json.loads(fixed_value)

        # adding the key-value pair to the dictionary
        json_data[key] = value

# Converting the dictionary to a JSON object
json_obj = json.dumps(json_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It gives the following error:
```
key, value = line.strip().split(': ')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Updated the answer, lemme know if that works.

Comment: Updated, lets see if it works.

Comment: Now it works without any errors, but only the first line is stored in json_obj.After printing json_obj: {"random_seed": " 42"}

Comment: Updated, check now

Comment: Still the same. You can cross-check with the file uploaded on Gdrive. 
Currently, it gives the output: 
{'random_seed': ' 42'}